# Doesnot show title on hover of sidebar menu icon when sidebar is collapse in AdminLTE

Tags: html, css, adminlte

In adminLte sidebar menu doesnot look proper.
If the text of the menu title is more then it should go to next line and in next line it should start exact below the first letter of first line.
I have done that but when it collapse and it is hover it is not showing menu title.
I have made some modification in code, my Html code is

```
<a href="#">
<div style="width:100%;display:inline-block;">
     <div style="width:10%;float:left;">
           <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
     </div>
     <div style="width:90%;float:right;display:inline-block">
         <div style="float:left;width:90%">
             <span style="padding-right: 50px;white-space: normal;line-height:14px">Dashboard Test Test Test Test</span>    
         </div>
                  <div style="float:left;width:2%">
                      <span class="pull-right-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </a>
```

Error image is showing arrow left side it should show arrow down : 
[image]
I have also made changes in AdminLTE.min.css file,the changes are as follows,

```
.sidebar-menu li > a > .fa-angle-left, .sidebar-menu li > a > div > div:nth-child(2)> div:nth-child(2) > .pull-right-container > .fa-angle-left {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: transform .5s ease;
    -o-transition: transform .5s ease;
    transition: transform .5s ease
}
.sidebar-menu li > a > .fa-angle-left, .sidebar-menu li > a > div > div:nth-child(2)> div:nth-child(2) > .pull-right-container > .fa-angle-left {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: transform .5s ease;
    -o-transition: transform .5s ease;
    transition: transform .5s ease
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: use `<div style="float:right;width:2%">` insted of float:left

Comment: I have a issue with title it doesnot show title on hover of sidebar menu icon

Comment: did you add CSS or js for hover effect?? if yes then add it to your question

Comment: No i have not added any special js or css for this i have made changes in the AdminLTE.min.css file only